# How can I convert the SQL in this Oracle stored procedure to dynamic SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

**THIS IS NOT A DUPE, THANKS**

I have this stored procedure that references dba_tables, and some others, a change means that these will have to become variables instead of hard coded values. So, I've been struggling to change the core SQL in the procedure, along with the variables, to dynamic SQL. I have made this question so that the tables as they are have their structure created for anyone that wanted to duplicate the problem. The end result would be a .csv file in your server directory, (which would have some values, if the relevant database links existed.) However, the entries below will produce a file and the procedure will compile successfully if copied as is. There's a database link in my version, that bit can either be replaced with your global_name or just removed, because the code will just look at your local dba_tables otherwise.

All I need, is for the code to compile and run successfully but using dynamic SQL instead so I can then put in any table variables... Can anyone help with this please?

```
--drop any tables before creating the new ones:

drop table TABLE_TRACKER;
drop table LINK_AND_MAIL;
drop table MV_PRD_SEG_DATA;
drop table bob_table;

--CONNECT AS YOUR USER:

CREATE DIRECTORY ESTIMATES AS '<path_name>';

GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY ESTIMATES TO <USER>;

create table TABLE_TRACKER
(
  TABLENAME         VARCHAR2(35),
  CREATED_AT        VARCHAR2(20),
  PDU_TAB_TRUNCATED VARCHAR2(1),
  TRUNCTIME         VARCHAR2(40)
)
/

insert into TABLE_TRACKER (TABLENAME, CREATED_AT, PDU_TAB_TRUNCATED, TRUNCTIME)
values ('IN_PROGRESS_20190530052803', '30/05/2019 17:34:09', 'Y', '31/05/2019 16:24:40');
commit;

CREATE TABLE "LINK_AND_MAIL" 
   (    "LINK_NAME" VARCHAR2(35), 
    "EMAIL_ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "MDATE" DATE
   )
/


insert into LINK_AND_MAIL (LINK_NAME, EMAIL_ADDRESS, MDATE)
values ('DATABASE', 'bob@bob.com', to_date('31-05-2019 16:25:31', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')); 
commit;

CREATE TABLE "BOB_TABLE" 
   (    "TARGETSCHEMA" VARCHAR2(200), 
    "PRODUCTIONSCHEMA" VARCHAR2(200), 
    "PRODUCTIONDATABASE" VARCHAR2(200), 
    "TABLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(200), 
    "DRIVER_TABLE" VARCHAR2(200), 
    "MANDATORY_JOIN" VARCHAR2(200), 
    "ADDITIONAL_JOINS" VARCHAR2(200), 
    "TABLE_COMPRESSED" VARCHAR2(200))
/

insert into BOB_TABLE (TARGETSCHEMA, PRODUCTIONSCHEMA, PRODUCTIONDATABASE, TABLE_NAME, DRIVER_TABLE, MANDATORY_JOIN, ADDITIONAL_JOINS, TABLE_COMPRESSED)
values ('SIT_BOB', 'APIBOB', 'DB1', 'PARMS', null, null, null, 'Y'); 
commit;

CREATE TABLE "MV_PRD_SEG_DATA" 
   (    "LINK" VARCHAR2(35), 
    "OWNER" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "SEGMENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(30),
        "FLAG" VARCHAR2(30),
        "SUM_BYTES" NUMBER)
/


insert into MV_PRD_SEG_DATA (LINK, OWNER, SEGMENT_NAME, FLAG, SUM_BYTES)
values ('DB1', 'BOB', 'GENRC_COLM', 'T', 5);
COMMIT;

/
```

---

```
--This is the start of the procedure, now you've created the tables 
--it should compile okay

create or replace procedure ESTIMATE_PROC_BOB is

--variables
l_dblink varchar2(100) := '<WHATEEVS>'; -- put your global_name here to mimic db_link
file_handle UTL_FILE.file_type;
v_ts_name varchar2(30);
v_link_name varchar2(10);
v_csv_name varchar2(100);
TOTAL_ROW_COUNT NUMBER;
TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB NUMBER;
FULL_TABLE_COUNT NUMBER;
EST_ONE_ROW_MB NUMBER;
C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT NUMBER;
SPACE_REQUIRED NUMBER;
v_total_driver_only NUMBER := 0;
--

begin

SELECT tablename into v_csv_name
FROM table_tracker
WHERE
CREATED_AT = (select MAX(CREATED_AT) from table_tracker);

select link_name into v_link_name from link_and_mail where mdate = (select max(mdate) from link_and_mail);
select distinct targetschema into v_ts_name from BOB_TABLE;

file_handle := utl_file.fopen('ESTIMATES_CSV', v_csv_name||'_EST_PROC.csv', 'w', 32767);

--

UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, ' ');
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, 'The below report shows total row counts in PROD ');
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, 'for entries with just a driver table only tables in the PDU document');
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, 'If you see no entries here, you have no valid joins in your file.');
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, ' ');
utl_file.put_line(file_handle, 'OWNER,TABLE_NAME,TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB,TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,FULL_TABLE_COUNT,EST_ONE_ROW_MB,SPACE_REQUIRED');

--main loop, this is the bit I need to be DYN SQL, can you help?

for rws in (
SELECT /*+ monitor parallel (4)*/ a.owner,
                        a.table_name,
                        b.driver_table,
                        b.mandatory_join,
                        sum(c.sum_bytes) TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB,
                        trunc(TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB / FULL_TABLE_COUNT,7) EST_ONE_ROW_MB,
                        (EST_ONE_ROW_MB * TOTAL_ROW_COUNT) SPACE_REQUIRED
                 FROM dba_tables a, 
                 BOB_TABLE b, 
                 MV_PRD_SEG_DATA c
                 WHERE a.table_name IN ( SELECT table_name
                                       FROM BOB_TABLE
                                       WHERE driver_table IS NOT NULL
                                             AND   additional_joins IS NULL
                                     )
                 AND   a.owner IN ( SELECT DISTINCT productionschema FROM BOB_TABLE c  )
                 and a.table_name = b.table_name
                 and a.table_name = c.segment_name
                 group by a.owner,a.table_name,b.driver_table,b.mandatory_join
               ORDER BY table_name
    )

loop

execute immediate' select /*+monitor parallel (10)*/ count(*) from ' ||rws.owner||'.'||rws.table_name || '@' || l_dblink||' b '||','||
rws.driver_table || '@' || l_dblink||' a ' ||' where ' ||rws.mandatory_join --||' and '||rws.additional_joins
into TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;

execute immediate' select /*+monitor parallel (10)*/ count(*) from ' ||rws.owner||'.'||rws.table_name || '@' || l_dblink
into C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;

utl_file.put_line(file_handle,
                      rws.OWNER || ',' ||
                      rws.TABLE_NAME || ',' ||
                      rws.TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB || ',' ||
                      TOTAL_ROW_COUNT || ',' ||
                      C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT || ',' || /* This is actually FULL_TABLE_COUNT*/
                      round(rws.TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB / C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,7)|| ',' ||
                      round(round(rws.TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB / C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,7) * round(TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,0),0)--SPACE_REQUIRED
                      );


v_total_driver_only := v_total_driver_only + round(rws.TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB / C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,7) * round(TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,0);

end loop;

UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, ' ');
utl_file.put_line(file_handle,
                     'Total Estimated Space Required '|| round(v_total_driver_only,0) ||' MB'
                     );
--

utl_file.fclose(file_handle);

end ESTIMATE_PROC_BOB;
/
```

Comment: Why on earth do you store DATE values (in `CREATED_AT`, `TRUNCTIME`) as string?

Comment: What is the reason for the `monitor` hint?

Comment: It puts runtime information into certain database views enhancing your ability to understand how long they take to execute and their impact on database performance.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of a cursor loop with dynamic SQL is a bit more involved than without dynamic SQL, but once you have seen a few examples it should become apparant how it works. Simple example from [PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference - 10g Release 1 (10.1) - OPEN-FOR-USING Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems034.htm):

```
DECLARE
   TYPE EmpCurTyp IS REF CURSOR;  -- define weak REF CURSOR type
   emp_cv   EmpCurTyp;  -- declare cursor variable
   my_ename VARCHAR2(15);
   my_sal   NUMBER := 1000;
BEGIN
   OPEN emp_cv FOR  -- open cursor variable
      'SELECT ename, sal FROM emp WHERE sal > :s' USING my_sal;
   ...
END;
```

Here is another example without the `USING` clause: [Open cursor with a dynamic select statement](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0500__Cursor/Opencursorwithadynamicselectstatement.htm)

Google will show you many more examples. Search for 'oracle open cursor dynamic sql'. One more example: [Dynamic SQL with ref cursor](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_dynamic_sql_ref_cursor.htm)